# 'command not found' after disk clone

Tags: server, cloning

I cloned the OS disk using a disk cloning device. Booting of Ubuntu off the cloned disk was successful, however, every command returned the error 'command not found.' If I reboot the machine it fixes the issue temporarily.

Can this issue be fixed or should I go about cloning the disk a different way.

The reason I'm cloning the disk is so that I can upgrade the OS from 11 to 14 but go back to the original disk if anything goes wrong with the upgrade.

Edit: I believe it is because the UID for the new disk is different, so the drive gets unmounted and certain commands and programs become inaccessible.

Comment: Did you make sure that you cloned the drive while you possessed root permissions? Was there any type of error code provided with the program? Also what tool did you use to clone your disk?

Comment: I did not use a tool, I used an external drive cloning device. It's like a 2 bay hdd dock with the ability to clone.

Answer (score 0):

I use [CloneZilla](http://clonezilla.org/) to do the exact same thing you're doing and never had any trouble *restoring* a clone.  *However I never boot the cloned disk*: I only use it to restore from... (as booting it would not make it identical any more as Ubuntu would immediately start installing updates which defies the reason for cloning)